# Need to bind DataList with Two DataSources

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am displaying some information in DataList. 
Can i bind the DataList to two DataSources.??
since i am facing a situation in which the two rows needs to be populated from two different Tables. Below is what i am trying to do.

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" id="myDataList">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column from DataSource1") %></b>
    <br />
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column from DataSource2") %>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to bind 2 data sources to a single item.

Ideally from database you must be getting the data by using the JOINS, if that is not possible than in your server side code make a datatable, fill it from the both data sources in such a way that in custom data table you have one row against each row in both data sources and than bind that data table with your data list.

```
DataTable customTable = new DataTable();
        customTable.Columns.Add("Column1");
        customTable.Columns.Add("Column2");

        DataRow drNew = null;
        foreach(DataRow dR in 1stDataSource)
        {
            foreach(DataRow dR1 in 2ndDataSource)
            {
                if(dR["ID"] == dR1["ID"])
                {
                    drNew = customTable.NewRow();
                    drNew["Column1"] = dR["Column1"];
                    drNew["Column2"] = dR1["Column2"];
                    customTable.Rows.Add(drNew);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        myDataList.DataSource = customTable;
        myDataList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be impossible for the DataSource to determine how to combine these two tables(inner join, cross join, etc). You will have to combine these yourself.
I too cannot give you code to combine them cause I don't know how your two tables are related.

If you have to do an inner join, just add the columns from the second data source to the first table and then loop over the rows to fill the table.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a datatable and imports the rows from each dataset to create one large datatable, then bind that.

However you will not be able to update from the databinder, though in the option provide by nunespascal, you can't do a simple update from dataset if you have done joins/crosses anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Cats";
    ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Products";
    ds.Relations.Add("children", ds.Tables["Cats"].Columns["categoryno"],
                         ds.Tables["Products"].Columns["categoryno"]);
    YourDataList.DataSource = ds;
    YourDataList.DataBind();
```